# Android 11 SAF - native fdopendir + readdir dont show full files list

Tags: android, c++, directory, android-ndk, storage-access-framework

In my application I use native function [fdopendir](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopendir). From java I get file descriptor which I put inside this function. Using it's result I can read content of the directory. On android 11 while listing the directory I see only media files. How to get full file list using Storage Access Framework?

here is my code :

In native code I iterate through directory entries using [readdir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html). dirp is my own structure which contains pointer to standard DIR structure.

```
struct dirent* dentry = readdir(dirp->dir);
```

To get DIR structure I jump to Java for file descriptor

```
DIR *AndroidStorage_OpenDir(const char *folder) {
    jstring string = jvmEnv->NewStringUTF(folder);
    int fd = jvmEnv->CallIntMethod( jvmCallbackThread, JavaOpenDir, string);
    jvmEnv->DeleteLocalRef(string);
    return fdopendir(fd);
}
```

In Java I use SAF method for getting integer file descriptor, then I return it back to c++

```
public static int openDir(String path) {
        Uri uri = uriCache.get(path);
        if (uri == null) {
            uri=getUri(path);
            uriCache.put(path, uri);
        }
    return resolver.openFileDescriptor(uri, "r").detachFd();
}
```

On Android 10 and lower it works fine. What should I do on android 11 to get all files inside directory? User granted me full access on this folder using **Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE**

EDIT: I opened [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199091106) on google's tracker, because it seems to me a bug. You can find there small application for reproducing. You can star the issue, so google can look at this this faster.